# sharing jsonbuilder files for index and show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonbuilder

Let's say I have a model called Customer. My `index.json.jbuilder` looks something like this

eg

```
json.array!(@customers) do |customer|
  json.extract! customer, :id, :name, :phone_number, :email
  # some more nested fields of customer
end
```

and my `show.json.jbuilder` also has similar duplicate code

```
json.extract! customer, :id, :name, :phone_number, :email
# some more nested fields of customer
```

is there a better way, say to include the show.json.jbuilder inside the index.json.jbuilder. I don't want duplicate the logic of rendering the json in two places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use partials (`partial!`) as described in jbuilder [documentation](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).